# Javascript action to slide my slider to the left or right

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am building a custom slider with JS/CSS. So far I have the following:

```
body { margin: 0; } 
div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
div#slider figure img { 
  min-width: 215px;
  width: 20vw; 
  height: auto;
  float: left; 
  margin-right: 5px;
}
div#slider figure { 
  position: relative;
  width: 140vw;
  min-width: 1535px !important;
  margin: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 0;
  /* animation: 30s slidy infinite; */
}

@keyframes slidyleft {
  0% { left: 0%; }
  100% { left: -20vw; }
}
@keyframes slidyright {
  0% { left: 0%; }
  100% { left: 20vw; }
}
```

and I use it as follows:

```
<div id="slider">
  <figure id="sliderfigure">

    <img src="image1.png">
    <img src="image1.png">
    <img src="image1.png">
    <img src="image1.png">
    <img src="image1.png">

   </figure>
</div>
```

In my Angular code, I have a button that calls to slide the slider to the left or right as follows:

```
var elem  = document.getElementById("sliderfigure");
elem.style.animation = '1s slidyleft'; 

var elem  = document.getElementById("sliderfigure");
elem.style.animation = '1s slidyright';
```

However, what happens is that it indeed it gets slided to the right or left, but that it in the end again returns to the original position.

How can I keep it at the future position?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use '1s slidyleft forwards' or '1s slidyright forwards' on the js

Comment: that definitely works, however, after having pressed it "right" (and it works fine), then how do you make it such that when I press "left" that it starts from that new position, instead of the original position

Comment: That would not work because when you press left it firts makes the left property set to 0 then make it -20vw to left. use transform: translate() instead.

Comment: that sort of works, but I can only press it once?

Comment: and again, it starts from the original position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you don't specify the `animation-fill-mode`, the default value will be `none`.
But to stay at the 100% state of the animation, you'll need `forwards`.

So you can write your animation like this :

```
var elem  = document.getElementById("sliderfigure");
elem.style.animation = '1s slidyright forwards';
```

See this for more infos :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode

Comment: works great, just two more questions: how can I make it such that the user can press it two times (so first +20vw then again +20vw), but capped at the length of the slider. Also how do you make it that when pressing right and then left, that left starts from the current position and not the original position of the element?

Comment: A CSS animation is running from a start frame to an end frame. So in you're case, it will start from 0 at each click. If you want it to move incrementaly, you shouldn't use an animation. You can use a transformation as FarzadYZ said, or directly a position with left/right properties. Translate seems to be easier through.